# Port is filtered by nmap

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, home-networking, tcp

#### Long story short:

I have opened a port one computer and I'm trying to access it from other computer in different network. **It's failing.**

#### Details:

I have 2 laptops:

`A` - `Ubuntu 16.04`, firewall off, connected to home router. **The router's firewall is off and I shut down every protection in it for this test.**
I set up java TCP server listening to port `50000` and menually setup my router to forward massages as follows:
[image]

**From machine `A` terminal:**

```
stavalfi@laptop:~$ sudo nmap <public-ip-of-A> -p 50000

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-11-26 19:08 IST
Nmap scan report for <public-ip-of-A>
Host is up (0.0028s latency).
PORT      STATE SERVICE
50000/tcp open  ibm-db2

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.58 seconds
```

---

`B` - windows 7, firewall off, connected to cellular network using LG3 phone in hotspot.

`B` can ping `A`.

**From machine `B` terminal:**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nmap <public-ip-of-A> -p 50000

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-11-26 19:11 Je
ime
Nmap scan report for <public-ip-of-A>
Host is up (0.046s latency).

PORT     STATE    SERVICE
50000/tcp filtered ibm-db2

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 35.17 seconds
```

Also `B` can control `A` using TeamViewer (port `5939` but when `B` try to nmap `A` on port `5939`, the port is filtered too.

#### My questions:

What is the problem? How can `B` see that port `50000` is open in `A`?

Comment: "connected to cellular network using LG3 phone in hotspot. " That is likely your problem. Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: Other networks (not cellular) see the same output: filtered port.